# Declaration & Initialisation of instance variables in java

Tags: java, class

Declaring and initialising instance variable of class in single statement is valid,
Something like...

```
public class Abc {
    private int d;
    private int e = 1;
    int f 
    =  2;

   (PSVM)
}
```

But, When I declare & initialise in separate statements, It wont work! Something like...

```
public class Abc {
    private int d;
    private int e = 1;
    int f;
    f = 2; //error

    (PSVM)
}
```

**NOTE :** I know java does not allow this, I am finding *reasons of such restriction.*

Can anyone please explain exact fundamental logic behind this..!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Because it's not in a block.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I know it is not allowrd, I want better explanation for that..!, Why not allowed?

Comment: because that's how the language is designed. Pre-empting your question about why the language is designed that way: you'd have to ask the language designers.

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay Thank you

Comment: @AndyTurner, but isn't that exactly the question: why did the language designers design Java in this way? While the designers might not be available, we can still reason about why they chose to design the language as they did.

Comment: @LittleHelper we can't answer that question: we can surmise as to why we *think* they designed it that way, and advantages and disadvantages it may confer, but that's merely speculation. Maybe there was a good technical reason; maybe it was Friday and they just wanted to get something working.

Comment: What you can do is use an instance initializer. The following will work:
int f;
{
    f = 2;
}

This does just the same as the initializer in your above example. And it's also the same as writing it into the constructor. I'd guess that the compiler moves all that stuff into the constructor. Here's some more info: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html?page=2

Comment: @AndyTurner, I believe that this is question is interesting because, if I were to design an object-oriented, imperative language like Java, I would like to know why the designers didn't allow this construct. I might be overlooking something that could be obvious to others. 
I believe that assignments on class level are not allowed because Java is object-oriented. Allowing assignments after initialization on the class level would allow programmers to code more procedurally.
While I don't know whether this is what the designers had in mind doesn't matter. It is still a valid point to address.

Comment: @LittleHelper but you can do it inside an instance initializer, which is no more or less "object-oriented". Assignments have no syntactic significance over and above any other statement expression; and statement expressions have no significance above any other statement. So, without making assignments special, that would mean you could write arbitrary statements at class level, and that would simply result in a sprawling mess.

Comment: @LittleHelper and there is no need to make them any more special than they are already: use an initializer on the field, or use an instance initializer block, or initialize in the constructor or regular method; there's no need for yet another way to do it. And yet, none of what I have said may be the reason why Java was designed this way; it's merely a consequence of the design.

Comment: @AndyTurner can yoy please un-check duplicate question flag!

Comment: @buzzingsilently why? It answers the question just fine.

Comment: Answer on the suggested link does not justify my question...That answer gives work around but not reason "why not possible in java?".

Comment: @buzzingsilently Eric Lippert has written an [excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/3788176) about asking this sort of question. Ignore the fact that he starts off discussing whether they are primarily opinion based; the points he raises after that are pertinent.